# REVTex 4.2 bibliography missing space after first author name

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I've got a document in REVTex (based off the apssample.tex template) that is exhibiting some odd behavior in the bibliography: For papers with two authors, the space between the first author's last name and "and" is missing, so that

> J. Smith and M. Jones

is rendered as

> J. Smithand M. Jones

If I switch the document from REVTex 4.2 to REVTex 4.1, then the bibliography renders as expected.

I haven't been able to track down this problem any more deeply -- e.g., the console output doesn't suggest anything obvious -- and my internet searches haven't turned up any other reports on this behavior.

Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: The problem is a bit difficult to reproduce at the moment. Where did you find the template, could you minimize that file and post it here? Just remove everything that is not related to the issue.

Comment: @Marijn While trying to set up a minimal example, I've tracked the problem down to a specific one-line change in the APS revtex bst file from version 4.1 to 4.2; I'm surprised that this hasn't caused wider problems and will contact the author of the file to find out why the change was made.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: Why was this question closed? It seems to me that the right course of action for improving this question would be for me to post a self-answer based on my comment of having tracked down the wrong behavior to a change in REVTex’s bst file, but I can’t do that while the question is closed.

Comment: Comment in lieu of an answer until I can post one: I've just gone back to my emails with the REVTex team and searched through their SVN logs. The bug was fixed in tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/revtex/… (specifically the change to line 1580), which had not propagated to the system I was using at the time of the question. I don't think it's worth my time at this point to build an MWE for a historical bug, when the answer is "Make sure you're using the up-to-date bst version".

Comment: I really don't understand the insistence on providing an MWE for a historical package-bug, where the relevant information for anyone reading this now is that: 1. Missing spaces are a problem that occurred in some versions of REVTex 4.2, and 2. The problem was acknowledged as a bug and has been fixed in recent versions.

Comment: @RLH as I mentioned as a possibility in my comment to your meta post, the question got closed again not because of the MWE, but because of the _cannot be reproduced_ reason, which is usually applied for fixed bugs (and also for some other cases, like an MWE that does actually produce an issue for the poster but not for other people because there is something strange happening with their installation).

Comment: @Marijn (putting aside that the close note is asking for an MWE) I'm still not clear on why a question about an issue that existed in previous distributions of LaTeX (this problem would have been either on Overleaf or a MacTex install) should be closed (which at least on other stackexchange site means "should not ever have existed"). This point seems to have been debated in multiple places on meta with no clear consensus, so I'll stop contesting it here. Thank you for putting the time into discussing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing space was caused by a bug in apsrev4-2.bst. The bug was fixed in [this update to the bst file](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/revtex/apsrev4-2.bst?pathrev=49751&view=diff&r1=49751&r2=49672&diff_format=h) (specifically the change to line 1580), which had not propagated to the system I was writing the paper on.